# NoMethodError - undefined method `split' for #<Hash:...:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree, braintree-rails

I'm creating a webhook notification with:

```
signature, payload = Braintree::WebhookTesting.sample_notification(
  Braintree::WebhookNotification::Kind::SubMerchantAccountApproved,
  rand(10000)
)
```

And then parsing with:

```
 @message = Braintree::WebhookNotification.parse(signature, payload)
```

Signature and Payload responses:

```
{:bt_signature=&gt;&quot;gcsg95j47yvzpgrr|61350cd9c99cbac6a7905479a5fa061976114e51&quot;, :bt_payload=&gt;&quot;ICAgICAgICA8bm90aWZpY2F0aW9uPgogICAgICAgICAgPHRpbWVzdGFtcCB0
 eXBlPSJkYXRldGltZSI+MjAxNS0wOS0wNFQwMjo1Nzo0NFo8L3RpbWVzdGFt
 cD4KICAgICAgICAgIDxraW5kPnN1Yl9tZXJjaGFudF9hY2NvdW50X2FwcHJv
 dmVkPC9raW5kPgogICAgICAgICAgPHN1YmplY3Q+CiAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
 ICAgICAgPG1lcmNoYW50X2FjY291bnQ+CiAgICAgICAgICA8aWQ+MzEzNDwv
 aWQ+CiAgICAgICAgICA8bWFzdGVyX21lcmNoYW50X2FjY291bnQ+CiAgICAg
 ICAgICAgIDxpZD5tYXN0ZXJfbWFfZm9yXzMxMzQ8L2lkPgogICAgICAgICAg
 ICA8c3RhdHVzPmFjdGl2ZTwvc3RhdHVzPgogICAgICAgICAgPC9tYXN0ZXJf
 bWVyY2hhbnRfYWNjb3VudD4KICAgICAgICAgIDxzdGF0dXM+YWN0aXZlPC9z
 dGF0dXM+CiAgICAgICAgPC9tZXJjaGFudF9hY2NvdW50PgoKICAgICAgICAg
 IDwvc3ViamVjdD4KICAgICAgICA8L25vdGlmaWNhdGlvbj4K
 &quot;}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `split' for #<Hash:0x007fdb043e7b50>:

App backtrace
-------------

 -  () Users/johnmolina/Documents/Rails/Nyvur/app/controllers/webhooks_controller.rb:30:in `handle'
 -  () Users/johnmolina/Documents/Rails/Nyvur/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
 -  () Users/johnmolina/Documents/Rails/Nyvur/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
```

I couldn't find much in the source code, and was wondering if someone else has encountered this issue also?

Here's the [Webhooks Controller](http://pastebin.com/fBniV3Vw).

Comment: Make sure you receive correct data in `signature` and `payload` before send them to the `parse` method. Just print them like: `puts signature.inspect` and see if its getting the correct data in the correct format.

Comment: I'll add what the response gave me.

Comment: I see the returned object is a hash. At some point, it tries to call the `split` method on a hash object and gets the error that you mentioned.  `split` method works with string objects.

Comment: Can you post your `webhooks_controller.rb` file? and mark line 30?

Comment: I'll put a link to pastebin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `Braintree::WebhookTesting.sample_notification` returns a hash, while the `signature, payload =` syntax expects an array.

You need to extract the signature and payload from the returned hash using their keys:

```
sample_notification = Braintree::WebhookTesting.sample_notification(
  Braintree::WebhookNotification::Kind::SubMerchantAccountApproved,
  rand(10000)
)

signature = sample_notification[:bt_signature]
payload = sample_notification[:bt_payload]
```